# Hangfire batching - does each job execute in the order in which its added to the batch?

Tags: hangfire

With batching, is each job executed in the order in which its added within the batch
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-batches.html

Say I had 3 different jobs, but would like them to execute in order 1-2-3 and 2 would only start after 1 was complete.  Does batching help in this case?  I would still need to at least define the start time with a chron schedule.